# tf.estimator.Estimator change weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

How can I manually edit the tf.estimator.Estimator weight tensors? The only information I was able to find on this was [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/16646) and it is wildly inefficient to reload an already loaded checkpoint, edit some tensors and then save the checkpoint. Ι'm working on [this model](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/deep_speech).